# How can I SUM an entire row based on what a cell to the left of the number is

Tags: google-sheets

So this is what my sheet looks like[image]

So basically I want to filter an entire row out, and in the cell (where the horrible function is that I have no idea what I'm doing) I want to show the SUM of all the cells where they're red, which basically means the checkbox to the left is empty `☐`.

So I need to filter `A5:Z5`, check if it's a number, and check if the cell to the left of it contains `☐`. Unless there is an easier way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any order as to where the numbers are? Will there always be 2 cells between 2 numbers ( and 1 of them is a ☐?)

Comment: You could check the Countif function

Comment: Why do you filter the range A5:Z5? It's a single row range, don't you want to summarize the whole table? It looks to me like you should be filtering A1:D5 instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(sumif(A5:Z5,"☐",offset(A5:Z5,0,1)))
```